# How to use strpos in php to create an if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, echo, strpos

I am trying to echo a strpos result, so I can build an if statement for it.
I am using the following code:

```
$response=json_encode((array)$client->GetData($request), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I get back a string:

```
{
    "GetDataResult": {}
}
```

Then I am trying to echo make a strpos() result:

```
echo(strpos($response,"Password"));
```

But this is not showing up in the browser console. It is as if this line of the code doesn't exist at all.

I need to use it in an if statement:

```
if (strpos($response,"Password") !== false) {
    return ($response);
}
```

As you can see, this statement should be untrue and therefore moved to the "else" statement, but for some reason it again ignores the strpos() and goes into the if statement.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/fNv9Y works as expected

Comment: As the string is JSON, you will probably be better off using `json_decode()` and then checking for the element existing (with `isset()`);

Comment: @u_mulder how is that possible? It doesn't work for me

Comment: Obviously, your `$response` is not what you show us. I don't understand what's the point of encoding to json and searching a substring there either.

Comment: @u_mulder I copied the response from the console. It's the exact string I'm getting when I use echo($response)

Comment: I don't know what console are you talking about. Why not just open php script in browser by direct link?

Comment: @u_mulder I'm talking about the browser console (debugger).

Comment: Then it's a result of some ajax request?

Comment: @u_mulder yes, it is exported by ajax. Do you think the ajax is showing it different than the PHP actual result? I mean, it's just a string, how different can it be?

Comment: I showed you the working example. Definitely console output differs from what is generated in php.